# How to fetch data from json API with three level

Tags: android, json, api

I am stuck in fetching data from json api. many times try but result is unsuccessful. Here is json pattern:

```
{
"All": [{
        "MainCategory": {
            "AllData": [{
                    "SubCategory": {
                        "AllData": [{

                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CHO1.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CHO1.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CHO1.jpg"
                            }, {

                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CHO100.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CHO100.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CHO100.jpg"

                            },
                            {
                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CHO101.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CHO101.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CHO101.jpg"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Attribute_Name": "Chocolate",
                        "Attribute_Value": "123",
                        "StockKeepingunit": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "SubCategory": {
                        "AllData": [{

                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CRI100.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CRI100.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CRI100.jpg"
                            },
                            {

                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CRI101.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CRI101.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CRI101.jpg"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Attribute_Name": "Crisps",
                        "Attribute_Value": "124",
                        "StockKeepingunit": null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Attribute_Name": "Confectionery",
            "Attribute_Value": "122",
            "StockKeepingunit": null
        }
    },

    {
        "MainCategory": {
            "AllData": [{
                "SubCategory": {
                    "AllData": [{

                        "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_YP100.jpg",
                        "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_YP100.jpg",
                        "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_YP100.jpg"

                    }],
                    "Attribute_Name": "Sub-Category",
                    "Attribute_Value": "163",
                    "StockKeepingunit": null
                }
            }],
            "Attribute_Name": "Your Category",
            "Attribute_Value": "162",
            "StockKeepingunit": null
        }
    }

],
"status": {
    "message": "success",
    "result": 1
}}
```

the data format is like

```
1. MainCategory1
       1.1 Subcategory1
           1.1.1 Product1
           1.1.2 Product2

       1.2 Subcategory2
          1.2.1 Product1
          1.2.2 Product2

2. MainCategory2
       2.1 Subcategory1
           2.1.1 Product1
           2.1.2 Product2
```

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: just want to store data in database from api.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem here are json parsing as per below.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray AllJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("All");
            for (int i = 0; i < AllJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject AllJsonObject = AllJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject mainCategoryJsonObject = AllJsonObject.getJSONObject("MainCategory");
                String mainCategoryName = mainCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Name");
                String mainCategoryValue= mainCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Value");
                JSONArray AllData1JsonArray = mainCategoryJsonObject.getJSONArray("AllData");

                for (int j = 0; j < AllData1JsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject AllData1JsonObject = AllData1JsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject subCategoryJsonObject = AllData1JsonObject.getJSONObject("SubCategory");
                    String subCategoryName = subCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Name");
                    String subCategoryValue = subCategoryJsonObject.getString("Attribute_Value");
                    JSONArray AllData2JsonArray = subCategoryJsonObject.getJSONArray("AllData");

                    for (int k = 0; k < AllData2JsonArray.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject AllData2JsonObject = AllData2JsonArray.getJSONObject(k);
                         String MainBigThumb = AllData2JsonObject.getString("MainBigThumb");
                        String MainImage = AllData2JsonObject.getString("MainImage");
                        String MainSmallImages = AllData2JsonObject.getString("MainSmallImages");

                        }

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit for it and convert your whole json data into Gson, which will make it a lot more easier.

first of all copy the response of your API and create your bean classes through

[this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site * By clicking source type to JSON * Annotation Style to GSON * Unticking useDoubleNumbers * Unticking AllowAdition Property

then copy those files to your project

then in your activity

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
APIServiceInterface apiController = retrofit.create(APIServiceInterface.class);
Call<Bean> result = apiController.studentLogin(username,password);

result.enqueue(new Callback<Bean>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Bean> call, Response<Bean> response) {
     // you  will get the reponse in the response parameter

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Bean> call, Throwable t) {

}
});
```

Where APIServiceInterface is the interface file.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, but you have to be cautious about the `{}`, `[]` and `,` while parsing `Json`. I will not write parsing code for you, instead just give an idea.

```
Intitial Json Response Object

Exract JsonArray named as "All" from above object

Get first Position Of above array, you will get an JsonObject

Extract a JsonObject from above object with name "MainCategory" 

Exract JsonArray named as "AllData" from above object

Get first Position Of above array, you will get an JsonObject

Extract a JsonObject from above object with name "SubCategory"

Exract JsonArray named as "AllData"  from above object

Get first Position Of above array, you will get an JsonObject

Containing following data,

                                "MainBigThumb": "rsz_0_800_CHO1.jpg",
                                "MainImage": "rsz_0_400_CHO1.jpg",
                                "MainSmallImages": "rsz_0_100_CHO1.jpg"
```